# jquery live click event doesn't work on iPad

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have some webpage with following code to bind click events

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(".groupLbl").live("click", function(e) {
    var $target = $(e.currentTarget);

        .....


    $.getJSON("/somelink.json", params, function(data) {
        if(data.success) {
                //success handler
        } else {
                                //fail handler
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

Works fine on PC browsers but doesn't work on iPad safari & chrome. I have other live events and they work fine on iPad. This page is part of popup so I wonder if this could be a problem?

Comment: No Java tag's please.and as a side not .live  has been deprecated from 1.7 jquery.

Comment: .live is also removed in 1.9+

Answer (score 1, accepted):

known feature/issue on Ipad

first click is considered as activating/hovering an element:
http://www.danwellman.co.uk/fixing-jquery-click-events-for-the-ipad/

Comment: But the artice was helpfull. Thanks